# Double cover of an orthogonal group

Tags: finite-groups

Let  $n \geq 3$, $(n, q) \neq (3,3)$ and $q$ be an odd prime power. It is known that $SO_{2n+1}(q)=\{A\in SL_{2n+1}(q): A^tJA=J\}$, where
 $J$ is a matrix with anti diagonal 1, 0 otherwise and $(SO_{2n+1}(q))'= B_n(q)$. Where can I find a complete description of the structure of the double cover of $B_n(q)$? Is this double  cover subgroup of $GL_{2n+1}(q)$?

Comment: For $n\geq4$, the derived subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, which is simple and has a double cover (which is not $S_n$) Is that also strange?

Comment: The double cover of $B_n(q)$ has twice as many elements as $B_n(q)$, so it has less than twice as many elements as $SO_{2n+1}(q)$ has, and that is much less than the number of elements $GL$ has.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am satisfied with $A_n$,  but since I always compar the $B_n(q)$  with $C_n(q)$, it seems strange to  me.  Is there any matrix representation for the double cover of $B_n(q)$  corresponding to the matrix representation of $B_n(q)$?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you mean by "strange".

Comment: I 'm going to change this word in the question.  I need to know about the structure of this group. Where can I find a complete description.